# App for "Minds of Modern Mathematics" doesn't work?

Tags: ipad, applications

I don't know how to send IBM a message to let them know to please fix this problem at the Apple App Store, but I have left a message at the ratings section of the App.

I have downloaded the free app at the Apple Store before on my iPad and it worked fine, but I lost all my data...long story... And now I want to get the app back, but I have tried four times to down load it and every time the app just displays a spinning wheel after the opening :'(

My intention is to let the Apple App Store and/or IBM know about this problem but can't find any link to report the problem. 
 [More details maybe found here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29404620#29404620) at the Apple Support Community.

Comment: Could you explain in a little detail "what doesn't work" and what your ideal solution would be? Are you just looking how to use the App Store to find the contact information support link for an App or are you needing to tell Apple that that link isn't doing what they purport it to do?

Comment: Pardon my brevity @bmike I have added some details :-)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving a review is generally the last way to get assistance since the developer and Apple do not reply to those - I resort to a bad/stinging review only after exhausting support from the vendor (or more than a month passes from the request for initial help or explanation.)

In all cases, Apple requires the developer to list a web site for each app. In the minds of mathematics case, since this is a free app, there doesn't appear to be a dedicated support, but if you click through to the developer site:

- http://mindsofmath.com there is an about page

It has an email address, so I would start with mailing them asking how to reach the developers support. In this case, your request isn't really best asked to the developer since you are having an issue installing it. You could ask them - perhaps they need to change the devices that the app supports.

In this case, it's installation and Apple should be contacted:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201398
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204084

The second article seems to have the best info - if you can't even get that app to install - http://reportaproblem.apple.com/ which seems to work best when you reach it from the HT204084 support page.